Automatically create related CSS file for Razor Component
Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to automatically create a CSS file when I create a new Razor Component?
For example:
When I create the file:
Component.razor

I want Visual Studio to automatically create the (blank) file:
Component.razor.css

